# What becomes the center of rotation when torque is applied?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque

Suppose a freely floating rod without any forces on it, and Now i apply a force perpendicular to the length of rod not through the center of mass, this causes rotation in the rod, but what becomes the axis of rotation if we observe the rod from an inertial frame not on the rod, and why exactly does that point becomes the axis of rotation?